# Could not get configured mojo for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check {execution: validate} Plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, eclipse-oxygen

Here is the screenshot of this issue. I've tried removing the entire .m2 and reinstalling java and eclipse still didn't works. I am using eclipse oxygen 3 and Java 1.8

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MKwq.png)

Comment: Hi, check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ensure you will receive more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your IDE as your using eclipse oxygen, Goto you eclipse installation directory where you can see an eclipse.ini file. The file is nothing but the startup configurations of the eclipse change your java path from "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin" to JDK path, Hopefully, this will work fine

Comment: I see, didn't get into the details anyway it Worked for me tnq Ms.Sruthy.